# center my footer divs

Tags: html, css

Hello I need help centering my footer divs (.footer-top). Basically I need the 'cottons story and contact' to sit in the middle all the time and not on the left.

[image: Original]

[image: Modified]

```css
.footer-container {
  padding-top: 35px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 24px;
} 
.footer-container .footer-top h3.module-title{

  text-transform: uppercase;
  
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Bell Gothic Blk';
  
}
.footer-container .footer-top h3.module-title:before{
 content: "";
  height: 1px;
  width: 60px;
  background: #464646;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
}
.footer-container .footer-top h3.module-title ul li a{
  line-height:1px;
}

.footer-container .images{
  text-align: center;

} 
.footer-container .icon{
  margin: 45px 0 25px;
  text-align: center;
} 
.footer-container ul.content{
  margin-bottom: 0;
} 


.footer-container div.content{
  max-width: 750px;
  font-size: 1.083em;
  margin: 0  ;
 

  text-align: left;

} 

.footer-top{padding:10px 0 0 0; }
.footer-container .footer-top .content{  
  padding: 0
}  
.footer-container .footer-top a{  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;font-size:16px; }  
.footer-container .footer-top a:hover{  text-decoration: none;} 
.footer-item-body i{font-size:20px;}
.footer-container .footer-top .newsletter {  padding: 0 15px;margin-bottom:30px;}
.footer-container .footer-top .newsletter .content{text-align:left;}
.footer-item-body .ft-line {color: #666666; padding-bottom: 5px;padding-left: 45px;text-align: left;}
.footer-item-body .ft-line i { color: #666666;float: left; margin-left: -40px; width: 40px;}

.footer-container .footer-top .newsletter .small-title{ margin-bottom: 20px;font-style:initial;font-weight:400;}

.footer-container .footer-top .newsletter .input-group-field{ 
  background: #ffffff;color: #c2c2c2; padding-left: 10px;margin: 0;border: 2px solid #ebebeb;
 width:100%;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:16px;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      height: 37px;

  display:table-cell;
}



.footer-container .footer-bottom address{font-size: 16px; padding: 5px 0 5px 0;    text-align: center;    text-transform: capitalize;font-weight:300;}

.footer-container .footer-top ul li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align:left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style:initial;
  
}
.footer-container .footer-top .content p{    
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
      padding: 0px 0 15px 0;
  
}
.contact-links li i{padding-right:20px; color: #cccccc;}
.button-about{
  text-align:left;
}
.button-about a, .content-blog .list-blog .button a{



 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;


}

.button-about a i{margin-left:10px;}
.footer-icon-share{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.footer-icon-share ul li{
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
 

}


.footer-icon-share ul li{
  position:relative!important;
}
.footer-icon-share ul li a{
  font-size:15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 10px;
}
.paypal-images{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.paypal-images ul li{
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;

}
```

```html
{% if settings.enable_footer_Top %}
 <div class="images">
        {{ 'logo_footer_top.png' | asset_url | img_tag }}
    </div>
 
    <div class="icon">
      {{ 'footer_icon_top.png' | asset_url | img_tag }}
    </div>
    
 {% if settings.footer_top_content != blank %}
  <div class="content" >
             {{ settings.footer_top_content }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Please see website:

https://cottonsaus.myshopify.com/collections/cottons-products

Comment: You're a chief designer and you don't know css?!! :o

Comment: Your comments are not very welcomed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-4` in `footer top` columns to make it center

Comment: Thanks for a great quick answer my friend